# C# Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Tags: c#

I want to add this code but it doesn't work. It is from a chat system, when a player connects to server I want in his textbox (chat) to show `HelloMsg` but when I start the program I get an error.

Sorry for my bad english!

```
#region ' Read Configuration.ini '
StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Database + "\\Configuration.ini");

string line = null;

while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Substring(0, 12) == "HelloMessage")
    {
        string[] StrMsg = line.Split('=');
        HelloMsg = StrMsg[1].Trim();
    }
}

Sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) expects two parameters, the start index and the length. You get this exception in two cases:

1. `startIndex` plus `length` indicates a position not within this instance.
2. `startIndex` or `length` is less than zero.

So you should handle that the string's length is less than 12:

```
while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Length >= 12 && line.Substring(0, 12) == "HelloMessage")
    {
        string[] StrMsg = line.Split('=');
        HelloMsg = StrMsg[1].Trim();
    }
}
```

A more readable and safer approach is using [`String.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(line.StartsWith("HelloMessage"))
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: .StartsWith was the nice simple answer for my issue. Thanks.